# Macos Ventura Disable Three Finger Tap Gesture

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults, preferences, macos-ventura, trackpad

How can I turn it off programmatically when the trackpad settings are set to "Tap with Three Fingers" in Macos Ventura operating system?

Option 1:

[image]

Option 2:

[image]

I tried the following defaults write commands but the changes are not applied without restarting.

I also try killall Dock and killall cfprefsd but it doesn't work.

```
defaults write com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad TrackpadThreeFingerTapGesture -int 0
defaults write NSGlobalDomain com.apple.trackpad.threeFingerTapGesture -int 0
defaults -currentHost write NSGlobalDomain com.apple.trackpad.threeFingerTapGesture -int 0
```

Do you have any suggestion for a solution for this problem?

Comment: Do you want to change the System Prefs setting or do you want to disable "Tap with Three Fingers" in  your app?

Comment: I want to disable "Tap with Three Fingers". Can I do it with any terminal command or static Objective-C function?

Answer (score 0):

Without restarting the computer, I activated the defaults with the code below.

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SystemAdministration.framework/Resources/activateSettings -u
```